# Join in Mysql query giving wrong output

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.They are as follows.

```
1.system_user_master 
________________________
user_id 
user_type
user_registeration_code
user_first_name
user_last_name

2.book_appointment
-----------------------
booking_id
booking_date
puser_id
duser_id
doctor_name

3.routine_queue_patient
----------------------
queue_id
booking_id
queue_checkin_time
puser_id
duser_id
qdoctor_name
```

Now i want the result like

```
patient_registeration_code, patient_first_name, patient_last_name, booking_date, queue_checkin_time
```

In routine_queue_patient booking_id can be null.I want the list of patient of current date of selected doctor who are in routine_queue_patient with booking_id has some value or can be null.if booking_id is null then it shows in booking_date in query result is null and if booking id exists in  routine_queue_patient then it display's the booking date.

I have written the query.The result is as follows.

```
booking_date | quecheck_in_time    |  user_first_name | user_last_name | user_regis_code          
2013-11-12   | 2013-11-12 15:50:53 |  rushang                                                                                                                                  |                                                                                                     patel           |  rp9898                                   |
2013-11-12   | 2013-11-12 16:00:11 |  anjana          |     bhatt      |     ab9087
```

The booking_date of rushang patel must come in null as in the routine_queue_patient the booking_id of rushang patel is null but i got the booking_date of second record in front of rushang patel.

The query I have written is as follows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.booking_date
              , r.queue_checkin_time
              , s.user_first_name
              , s.user_last_name
              , s.user_registeration_code 
           FROM routine_queue_patient r 
           JOIN system_user_master s
             ON r.puser_id = s.user_id
           JOIN book_appointment b  
             ON ((b.booking_id = r.booking_id) OR r.booking_id is NULL) 
            AND DATE(r.queue_checkin_time) = '2013-11-12'
          WHERE r.qdoctor_name = 'kashyup Nanavati'
            AND DATE(b.booking_date) = '2013-11-12'
```

Thanks
Rushang

Comment: What's the `or r.booking_id is NULL and DATE(r.queue_checkin_time) like '2013-11-12'` part into the join between book_appointment and routine_queue_patient ? I don't get it

Comment: i want the records who's booking id is null in the routine_queue_patient and r.queue_checkin_time is for today's record

Answer (score 1):

The join with book_appointment table is wrong. You shouldn't try to join on a null value.
Use left join to do it : it will join if a correspondant row is found, else all joined table columns will be null.

=>

```
   SELECT DISTINCT b.booking_date
          , r.queue_checkin_time
          , s.user_first_name
          , s.user_last_name
          , s.user_registeration_code 
       FROM routine_queue_patient r 
       JOIN system_user_master s
         ON r.puser_id = s.user_id
  LEFT JOIN book_appointment b  
         ON (b.booking_id = r.booking_id AND DATE(b.booking_date) = '2013-11-12')
      WHERE r.qdoctor_name = 'kashyup Nanavati'
        AND DATE(r.queue_checkin_time) = '2013-11-12'
```

Comment: BTW, is this really necessary to check b.booking_date ? You already check r.queue_checkin_time. Is that a 1 to 1 relation between the two tables, for one given row ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your query.I got the null when there is null bookin_id in routine_queue_patient but i got the queue_checkin_time equals to booking_date.I dont get the actual booking_date from the book_appointment table.Can you please tell me how can i resolve it?

Comment: If r.booking_id is null, it means there's no corresponding row into book_appointment, no ? So how do you want to get book_appointment.booking_date if row doesn't exist ?

Comment: no i dont want the booking date for the null records.but i want the booking_date for the records which have the booking_id.Right now the problem is i am getting the queue_checkin_time as the booking_date which is wrong.I am getting the value of queue_checkin_time as the booking_date.I am not getting the right value of book_appointment table for those who have booking id.

Comment: for example suppose i have booked the appointment on 2013-11-13 17:00:00 but the queue_checkin_time is 2012-11-13 17:30:00.So from the above query i am getting the booking_date is 2012-11-13 17:30:00 which is wrong.I want the booking_date is 2013-11-13 17:00:00.

Comment: Yes you do, b.booking_date is b.booking_date. Are you sure of your data ?